# Why was Harry so good at Quidditch?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Okay, we know that Harry Potter was unusually good at Quidditch. Why? Most of his other unusual abilities, we have explained, but this one hasn't really, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Part of it is purely physiological skills (reaction time, hand-eye coordination, balance, spacial orientation) that are heritable, and we know his father possessed the same skills, so Harry was likely to inherit them.

Part of it is Harry's flying ability (which is part physiological and again heritable, and part magical - e.g control of the broom -  plausibly heritable but that's just a guess).

Part of it is Harry's innate fearlessness - he was willing to do risky stuff that yielded Snitch catches (standing up on a broom?!?!?!) that a "more sane" person would consider unacceptable risk.

And yet another part of it is simply a good amount of practice. I have heard many trainers make a claim that any physically-non-impaired person can be trained to perform at least on the level of a decent sportsman given enough motivation - which Harry had in spades since he loved flying and Quidditch. Please note that Harry was not a super-level Seeker - he never considered becoming a professional player. He was merely better than opposite players in his school.

Comment: Interestingly, it appears that point #4 might not be true; http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-31945687

Answer (score 5):

Pure speculation, because as the questioner states, this wasn't ever given a definitive answer:

1. Hermione opines that the skill of "Seeker" was in Harry's blood, owing to the fact that his father had been a celebrated player during his time at Hogwarts.
2. Harry, in his anger and irritation with Draco Malfoy, boarded a broom, and took off after him without any complete lesson in riding/handling the apparatus. This suggests an innate ability, or perhaps just an ability to tackle an issue without giving it much thought in the haste of the moment. (aside from the fact that we learn in later books it wasn't Harry's first time on a broom; he had one as a tiny child)
3. Everyone that walks this planet has an effortless talent that time and practice perfects into an unbeatable skill. Sure, there may be records broken in sports, and in other areas of life, but what can never be eclipsed is the personal journey to that achievement.
4. I believe Harry's good skills in Quidditch were reflected upon with
   great reviews because this is a young boy who did not grow up in the 
   wizarding world, but picked up the game quickly despite that odd. This 
   also was all own his own merit; as Voldemort has no connection to 
   Quidditch. This is the part of Harry where he is completely himself, and
   perhaps walking in the faded footsteps of his father.

I agree that the Quidditch portions of these books would not have been as interesting without at least one of the main characters participating in the sport. Although the Quidditch World Cup chapters in book 4 were entertaining, they were more about the reaction of Harry and his friends, as opposed to the action on the Quidditch Pitch.

Comment: Voldemort might have no connection to Quidditch, but he sure can fly well.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to note is that Sirius got Harry a toy broomstick for a birthday present before the Potters died (noted in Lily's letter in Deathly Hallows), so on top of whatever he inherited from his father (McGonagall mentions in Book 1 James was an excellent quidditch player), the instincts Harry had immediately upon getting on a broom in the Sorcerer's Stone to chase Malfoy were born from his experiences as a very young child.